# How to get video metadata from DataTransfer.files from drag and drop without uploading file to memory

Tags: javascript, file, drag-and-drop, metadata

I got this code

```js
let targDrop=document.querySelector(`[data-drop="simb1"`)
targDrop.addEventListener("dragover",function(e){e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();e.dataTransfer.dropEffect='copy'});
targDrop.addEventListener("drop",drop);
function drop(e){
  e.preventDefault();e.stopPropagation();
  let file=e.dataTransfer.files[0];
  //get metadata
}
```

I just want to get the metadata if the file is a video but I don´t want to put the objet to memory because it can be a large file